# Getting Admin Creator of comment using Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Using Access token has privilege `manage_pages`. I can get admin creator (`admin_creator` field) of any **post** in a page I'm admin in, but how can I get **comment** **admin creator** ?

Comment: You can't, because that field does not exists for comments.

Comment: @CBroe I know it's only for post , but um asking for a work around to do the same for comments

Comment: There is no workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You must make a request to the facebook api like this: `{post-id}?fields=message_tags,from` inside `message_tags` you will get an array with the userid creators of every comment of the current post.

Hope it´s not too late...